# Create a QA site similar to StackExchange on SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, architecture, capacity-planning

One of our client wish to implement a smart collaboration process for its vast pool of employees around 50k located across different continents. They already have SharePoint 2010 enabled as the primary medium of Office Collaboration. As part of scaling their existing knowledge management process, they have opted for having a QA based system for all divisions/departments.

I'm looking for some really interesting inputs here as to how SharePoint can be leveraged to serve as a robust QA based system. I have already identified a few capabilities of SharePoint (like Enterprise Search , Managed Metadata, Workflows ,etc.) that can be of great assistance.

Initially the system is proposed to be fairly a simple prototype without much of the advance features like tag subscriptions , bookmarking tags or ignoring tags, setting bounties etc,.

The primary requirements are 
**Voting System 
 basic QA engine 
Roles Management with simple moderation 
Tagging  
Reputation based Ranking 
 Search 
Flaging**

Please let me know what capabilities of SharePoint can be leveraged to address this requirement. Any architectural or capacity planning inputs are also welcomed.

Comment: This is really a statement of requirements rather than a question. Please refer to our [FAQ](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask), but specifically questions should be "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face". It will be closed for now, but do feel free to edit your question to re-form it as a specific answerable question and flag it for moderator attention and we will re-open it once it meets the guidelines. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20321/sharepoint-qa-tool-like-stack-exchange and http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5240/enhanced-sharepoint-discussion-forum-qa